# Android Toolbar has more padding than ActionBar, how to fix

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar

I had to replace the actionbar to implement new UI patterns the design team wanted

The actionbar is now replaced with the ToolBar but the toolbar object is bigger than the actionbar, only marginably, but it is noticeable and not desired

Here is the XML declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

How do I make it smaller? I used to be able to rely on `actionBarSize` which is already predefined for every screensize, I can put in a specific dp value but is that the solution for this object?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just bigger because the Material theme has bigger action bars? That is an expected change when moving from a non-material Action bar.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm not sure, so my application is using the parent theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and my appcompant dependency is v7 version 21+ , so I guess this is possible, how do I fix the height though?

Comment: So what you're saying is that using an AppCompat version 21 `ActionBarActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light` gives you an action bar a different height from a Toolbar in a `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` with everything else the same?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, the toolbar object takes up a greater height than the actionbar object, even when the toolbar's height is set to `?attr/actionBarSize`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?attr/actionBarSize is 56dp with new support lib. So even if you stick to actionbar you will get a bigger size. Set actionBarSize in your theme.